# Mutation Doesn't Set Value in State

Tags: vue.js, vuex, mutation

I set values with [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html), but it doesn't update values in state object. It creates new variables inside `mutations` object.
[image: img]

mutations.js:

```
const mutations = {
  setUser(state, user) {
    state.user = user; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
  },
  setToken(state, token) {
    state.token = token; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
  },
  setAuthenticated(state, authenticated) {
    state.authenticated = authenticated; // eslint-disable-line
  },
};


export default {
  mutations,
};
```

state.js:

```
const state = {
  callingAPI: false,
  activeSidebar: true,
  searching: '',
  authenticated: null,
  user: null,
  token: null,
  userInfo: {
    messages: [],
    notifications: [],
    tasks: [],
  },
};

const getters = {
  isAuthenticated: (state) => { // eslint-disable-line
    return state.authenticated;
  },
  isActiveSidebar: (state) => { // eslint-disable-line
    return state.activeSidebar;
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
};
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import state from './state';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    state,
    mutations,
  },
});
```

I update a value with `commit` function. e.g.: `this.store.commit('setAuthenticated', true);`

```
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import store from '../store';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'setAuthenticated',
      'setUser',
      'setToken',
    ]),
  },
  store,
  login(context, creds) {
    context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(creds)).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const bodyText = response.bodyText.split('\n');
          const token = bodyText[0].split(' ');
          let redirect = bodyText[1];
          redirect = redirect.substring(redirect.indexOf('[') + 1, redirect.indexOf(']'));
          this.store.commit('setToken', token[1]);
          this.store.commit('setAuthenticated', true);
          ...........
         });
      }
```

Isn't it supposed to update null values in `state` object instead of creating new variables in `mutations` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misusing modules. I'll assume you aren't actually trying to use them. You also have unintended property nesting with your `state` import.

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {state,getters} from './state';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer led how I should define those ones in `Vuex.Store()` with few more changes.